# jQuery - index keeps resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a lot of data, and for some reason the index of `input` after every `<td> </td>` keeps resetting. For that I have created this function

```
$('.custom-input').each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr('data-index', index);
});
```

But on the "change function" when I try to use it, it does not work.

My current code:

```js
$('.custom-input').each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr('data-index', index);
});

$('.custom-input[data-index=" '+index+' "]').on('change', function() {
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td>
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
  </td>
  <td>
     <!-- The index for the next input should not be reset -->
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `index()` does not reference a `data-index` attribute.  You need to use the `attr('data-index')` getter if you are using the `attr()` setter

Comment: Your code is throwing an error.

Comment: @Taplar, How do I reference to the data index attribute?

Comment: I just showed you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is not working because you are trying to attach it to each specific element using an index variable that doesn't exist. I don't know the purpose of what you are doing, but you should be attaching the event to all `.custom-input` elements. Also, I would suggest using the `input` event rather than `change`.

> The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or
>   `<textarea>` element has been changed.
>
> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each alteration to an element's value.

```js
$('.custom-input').each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr('data-index', index);
   console.log("data-index set to: " + $(this).attr('data-index'));
});

$('.custom-input').on('input', function() {
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
  </td>
  <td>
     <!-- The index for the next input should not be reset -->
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
     <input class="custom-input" type="text" value="0">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Small side note; you should avoid the mixed usage of `attr()` and `data()`.  `data()` caches values, while `attr()` does not.  So there is always the chance that you access a data attribute with `data()` and change it with `attr()`, the value returned from `data()` would not change.  So to always be safe you should stick with using just `attr()` or `data()` and not intermix the usages.

Comment: @Taplar Good information to know. I updated the answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you remove whitespace around index on this jquery selector? like this:

```
$('.custom-input[data-index="'+index+'"]').on('change', function() {
   alert($(this).index());
});
```